# localstorage how to save a button

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I managed to save the text that is in the input field but the problem is that i do not know how to save the button. The buttons turn white when i click on them and the price of that seat will be visible in the input field. The price saves but the button does not stay white.

```
<script>

function changeBlue(element) {
    var backgroundColor = element.style.background;
    if (backgroundColor == "white") {
        element.style.background = "blue";
        add(-7.5)
    } else {

        element.style.background = "white";
        add(7.5)
    }

}

function add(val) {
var counter = document.getElementById('testInput').value;
var b = parseFloat(counter,10) + val;

    if (b < 0) {
        b = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('testInput').value = b;
    return b;

}


    function save(){

    var fieldValue = document.getElementById("testInput").value;
    localStorage.setItem("text", fieldValue)
    var buttonStorage = document.getElementsByClass("blauw").value;
    localStorage.setItem("button", buttonStorage)

}

function load(){

    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("text");
    if(storedValue){

    document.getElementById("testInput").value = storedValue;

    }
    var storedButton = localStorage.getItem("button");
    if(storedButton){

    document.getElementsByClass("blauw").value = storedButton;

    }
}


</script>

<body onload="load()">

 <input type="text" id="testInput"/>
 <input type="button" id="testButton" value="Save" onclick="save()"/>
 <input class="blauw" type="button" id="testButton2" value="click me to turn white"
 style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">
 <input class="blauw" type="button" id="testButton2" value="click me to turn white"style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">


</body>
```

i made a small sample of what i want to do. And i do not want to use the Id's of the buttons because i have like 500 of them in a table.

Comment: So shorten it. Abstract away the bits we don't need. _Post a testcase_. Don't just omit important things because they are "too long".

Comment: No, I said shorten it. Not post everything!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is right. This code isn't helpful. It's even missing the input field you mentioned in your answer. So even if I throw it into a fiddle to see what you're doing, it throws an error. You should post a short test case with a couple elements and simple javascript as an example. Just a note: Your `id` attributes should be UNIQUE. Perhaps then, you could save in localstorage the IDs of the elements you want colored - and loop through on page load to recolor.

Comment: Sorry i posted it but i didn't had enough spaces in front of it.

Comment: I have changed it to a sample of what i want to achieve

Comment: Just a word of advice, program in one language: don't use `white` and `blauw` together, it's still `blue` in english

Answer (score 0):

That's because `getElementsByClass` (it's `getElementsByClassName` btw) returns a **node list** of all the elements with that class.

To make it work, you need to go through all the items in the list, using a for-loop, and set the value of each individual element to the localStorage-value.

See these links for more information:
[**Link 1**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
[**Link 2**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

---

**Very small mockup to give you an idea:**

*(In the JS, I put in comments the lines of code you would be using for your situation.)*

```js
function changeValues() {
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("child"); //var list = document.getElementsByClassName("blauw");

  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    list[i].innerHTML = "Milk"; //list[i].value = storedButton;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="example">
  <li class="child">Coffee</li>
  <li class="child">Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to change the text of the first list item (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="changeValues()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand what u mean

Comment: @CeesvandenToren - Added some links and a code snippet

Comment: But how will the localStorage.setItem() look like?

Comment: but i dont need to change anything because the buttons already change to white but the problem is, is that when i close the browser and open it again that the buttons stay white and not blue

Comment: the line before `localStorage.setItem()` should look something like this: `var buttonStorage = document.getElementsByClassName("blauw")[0].value;`. You can find this at the very top of the second [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbyclassname.asp), have you even looked at it?

Comment: i mean what do i need to put between the brackets of localStorage.setItem()

Comment: what you have now. (You say that works for `fieldValue`, then it should work here as well)

Comment: you should however put `;` at the end of both of those lines